# Extract certain parts from XML string

Tags: c#, xml, winforms

I have a windows form in C# that does a httpclient get request. And this is the response in XML format

```
>  <Result><Success>true</Success><Token>MYTOKENHERE</Token><TokenExpirationDate null="1"
> /><UserName>********</UserName><PersonCode>442078</PersonCode><LoginStatusMessage>LoginOk</LoginStatusMessage></Result>
```

I want to set the text of a text box to what is inbetween the `<Token></Token>` Tags

What is the best approach to do this

Thanks

This is my current Form1.cs code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace EBS_Token_Form
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

     

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            HttpClient Client = new HttpClient();
            Client.BaseAddress = new Uri("PRIVATE_URL");

            string Username = username.Text;
            string Password = password.Text;



            string CredentialsString = $"{Username}:{Password}";
            byte[] CredentialsStringByes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(CredentialsString);

            Client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("basic", Convert.ToBase64String(CredentialsStringByes));

            try
            {
                var Response = Client.GetAsync("Rest/Authentication").Result;

                if (!Response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    // Something went wrong, is error.
                    // Put a breakpoint on the line below and we can figure out why.
                    string x = "";
                }

                string ServerResponse = Response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

              
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return;
            }


        }
```

If i set the value of the textbox to `ServerResponse` it has the full xml document. I need to extract just the .

Comment: Is XmlSerializer what you're looking for?

Comment: If it were me, I would deserialize the XML to a class or dictionary-like structure, or use an XML parser to get that element and its value. There's not one "right" way and there are plenty of examples of both here.

Comment: Deserialize the thing with XmlSerializer. Presumably you need the other values anyways also. For example when Success is false Token might not be there.

Comment: ^^ https://dotnetfiddle.net/A0vxeS

Comment: @Fildor That doesn't implement into myButton1_Click event. I'll add my current code to my question

Comment: Do not use `.Result`. Go async all the way. => `await Client.GetAsync();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually I'd use [XmlSerializer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer?view=net-6.0) for something like this, but if you really just need this one value, you may want to try [XElement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.linq.xelement?view=net-6.0):

```
var root = XElement.Parse(yourResponseString);
var value = root.Element("Token")?.Value;
```

XElement is great for traversing, reading and manipulating XML.

Comment: This seems a better answer.

Comment: For the exact opposite super-speedy but gibberish readability, "string Result_Two = Incoming_XML.Substring(Incoming_XML.IndexOf("<Token>") + "<Token>".Length, Incoming_XML.IndexOf("</Token>") - (Incoming_XML.IndexOf("<Token>") + "<Token>".Length));" also works. :D

Comment: This works! to an extent, the text isn't in the textbox i.imgur.com/jUOJMzb.png –

Comment: There's nothing in the code you've presented dealing with displaying the token, Lewis.  Although, if I were to guess, looking at the screenshot, you're assigning the token to a Label and have a separate rectangle drawn in the wrong place.  Or vice versa, the label being in the wrong place.

Comment: The box is a textbox called finalToken and in code i have `finalToken.Text = value;`

Comment: And the hexadecimal "9BD789833..."is the received token, right?  I practically guarantee that finalToken is a Label, not a TextBox.  username and password _are_ clearly TextBoxes.  Double check in design view.  TextBox, by default, is white background with border, whereas a Label has a transparent background with no border.

Comment: @CJPN You are right i was referencing the wrong object :facepalm:

Comment: If it's any consolation, I spent four hours the other day digging around the innards of a production web server searching out weird behaviour, only to discover a "v" had been typed as "w" in a critical place.  Sometimes you just need to stare angrily at the machine for long enough in order to spot the obvious mistake.

Answer (score 1):

XPath works for this, although some might consider overkill.  The XPath expression /Result/Token/Text() does exactly what it looks like it will.

```
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.XPath;

string Incoming_XML = @"<Result><Success>true</Success><Token>MYTOKENHERE</Token><TokenExpirationDate null=""1"" /><UserName>********</UserName><PersonCode>442078</PersonCode><LoginStatusMessage>LoginOk</LoginStatusMessage></Result>";

XPathDocument xPathDoc = null;

using (StringReader sr = new StringReader(Incoming_XML))
{
    xPathDoc = new XPathDocument(sr);
    XPathNavigator xPathNav = xPathDoc.CreateNavigator();
    string Result = xPathNav.SelectSingleNode("/Result/Token/text()").Value;
    Console.WriteLine($"Token is: {Result}");
}
```

Answer (score -2):

below sample code may not the best but it is simple to understand and will do the work.

```
        // Define a regular expression pattern 
        string Regex_syntax = @"<Token>[\s\S]*?</Token>";

        
        Regex rx = new Regex(Regex_syntax,RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);


        // Define a RAW data string to process , in your case will be http response result
        string inputtext = @"<Result><Success>true</Success><Token>MYTOKENHERE</Token><TokenExpirationDate";


        // Find matches.
        MatchCollection matches = rx.Matches(inputtext);

        // clease the uneeded string 
        string cleanseString = matches[0].ToString().Replace(@"<Token>", "");
        cleanseString = cleanseString.Replace(@"</Token>", "");

        // This will print value in between the token tag
        Console.WriteLine("require output = " + cleanseString);
```